# Desktop app authentication and storing credentials

Tags: python, api, authentication, flask, token

I am revisiting my old code trying to improve it. It's Windows desktop client written in Python that interacts with a Flask API to access data from a PostgreSQL database. The user authenticates and gets a JWT access token. Previously I stored them simply in the .py file like this:

```
access_token = eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c
```

Looking at this code now I realize how unsafe this solution was.

**My main question is what are the best practices for securely storing the access tokens for desktop Apps?**

Alternatively: best practices for authenticating users in Python desktop apps

Most solutions I see on Stack Overflow are tailored to web applications (localstorage, cookies etc.). Others mentioned storing the token in a separate file and obfuscating/encrypring it. Some mentioned storing the token in Windows Credentials Manager. Some suggested using OAuth2 instead (I am considering this option as well)

However, I can't find any legit resources on how desktop apps (Windows, MacOs, Linux) store user credentials so that users don't have to log in every 30 minutes. *For example you log into the Spotify app once and you don't have to log in ever again.*

Any tips/suggestions/resources would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When a user logs in and provided their information is correct. To stop them signing in again and again at each runtime you can store their information in a file (preferably encrypted) and at runtime use that to log in. This also allows the user to edit the information

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But isn’t the encryption key then stored in the .py file? In my understanding it simply adds just one step to reverse engineer it. By reverse engineering the python file you get the encryption key and use it to decrypt the credentials file. Am I missing something?